# Symfony3 The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am new to symfony and I am trying to pass a object from a list to a new page using:

`<a href="{{ path('fooUpdate', { 'id': item.id }) }}">Update</a>`

The list `({% for item in list %})` of Foo objects is fine, the objects are fully loaded from the database, but the link does not work because of this Doctrine error:

`The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\Foo`

Here is the Foo class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo") 
 */
class Foo {

/** 
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")    
 */
private $description;

//getters and setters
```

And here is the controller method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/fooUpdate/", name="fooUpdate")
 */
public function updateAction($id, Request $request) {
    $foo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Foo')->find($id);
    return $this->render('/foo/fooUpdate.html.twig', array(
            'foo' => $foo
    ));
}
```

The link itself looks like it is working, because the URL of the error is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/fooUpdate/?id=1
```

So what am I missing?

Also, is there any way of doing this using POST, so the id will not appear in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the id in the route:

```
@Route("/foo/fooUpdate/{id}", name="fooUpdate")
```

Comment: Oh thanks! It worked, but any idea on how to do it via post?

Comment: Assuming you have a form or similar to send your post data. You have to configure your route as * @Method({"POST"}) then in your controller action get you post vars. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should also set defaults:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/fooUpdate/{id}",
 *      defaults={"id" = 0},
 *      name="fooUpdate")
 */
```

The defaults are used in case you don't pass in a parameter.

As far as not setting the id in the URL, look into sessions:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

You should be able to do that, but it's more work (coding).