# symfony 2.8 has problem making checkout module (CLOSED)

Tags: php, cart, checkout, symfony-2.8

EDIT: so im closing this thread because i change my method how to make checkout so im closing this and will update my newer method how to achieve the result i expected :) cheer and thank you for you guys who want to help me

ORIGINAL POST
I am in a difficult situation to make checkout function in my little project and I found the solution in here.

[Symfony 3 problems with getting the price and name right on my checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809083/symfony-3-problems-with-getting-the-price-and-name-right-on-my-checkout)

but when I adopt the solution and try to check out I got this error message...

> The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\Product

so what step I should do to fix this

I've done googling with keyword The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle and open some thread in stackoverflow like this one
[Symfony3 The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371023/symfony3-the-identifier-id-is-missing-for-a-query-of-appbundle-entity)

and this
[Symfony3 The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371023/symfony3-the-identifier-id-is-missing-for-a-query-of-appbundle-entity)

and this
[Symfony3 The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371023/symfony3-the-identifier-id-is-missing-for-a-query-of-appbundle-entity)

but still not fix my issue

here its my checkout code

```
/**
 * @Route("/checkout/{id}", name="cart_checkout")
 */
public function checkout()
{
    $session = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());

    foreach($cart as $id => $quantity) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find(key($cart));
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find(key($cart));

    return $this->render('checkout/index.html.twig', array(
        'product' => $product,
        'price' => $product->getPrice(),
        'name' => $product->getName(),
    ));
}
```

and this is my checkout view

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %} 

   {% block body %}
    <h1>Checkout</h1>
    {% if empty is defined %}
        <h5>Your shopping cart is empty.</h5>
    {% endif %}

    {% set cart = app.session.get('cart') %}

    {% if product is defined %}

        <ul class="thumbnails">
        {% if app.session.flashbag.has('notice') %}

            <div class="flash-notice">

                {{ app.session.flashbag.has('notice') }}

            </div>

        {% endif %}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </thead>
    {% for key, item, price in cart %}
        <tr class="col-span-6">
            <td><b>{{ name }}<b></td>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
            <td>{{ price }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ path('product_display') }}">Product</a>

{% endblock %}
```

href from cart view

```
<td><a href = "{{ path('cart_checkout', { 'id': x.Id }) }}">Checkout</a></td>
```

I expect the output should be proccess the cart to checkout successfully without a problem so maybe little help with this

Comment: well the error clearly says: do you have the primary key set on the product entity?

Comment: @HaiderAli ok maybe its silly question how i know the primary key i set in entity? i have $id in product entity and i guest its the PK in product entity

Comment: go it, then it has something to do with your cart. What does your cart array looks like?

Comment: do you have the cart products listed fine on the view?

Comment: please post var_dump of your cart array